# How to get Full Name in 'Calculated Column' from User Id in SharePoint List

Tags: list, active-directory, calculated-column

I have a list with a column which consist of user id. there is also a **calculated column** which has to get the **full name from this id**. I was able to achieve this by installing custom  WSP.
Is there any way to get this **Full Name just by entering calculated value in the column**(or Out of Box)?

Suppose,if we use 'Created By' field ,the problem is the data displayed under 'created by' field would be  LastName,FistName. When use it for email purposes, it will be displayed as domain\username. Instead of this i need to display the name as FirstName,LastName.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't think you can do it with a calculated column, but you can use a list workflow to set a text field.

Add a Set Field in Current Item action. Configure the value with User Profiles as data source and select the Name field from source. Then match the Account Name field (only option available) to the column with your User ID (assuming that the user id is the user's logon name).

If you use a Content Type instead of creating columns directly on the list, you can set the full name column as Hidden so that it doesn't show in forms.

Answer (score 0):

The Created By field shows the users Full Name by default.  Is there a particular reason why this can't be used?

Comment: Yes,but it shows the name as domainname\username.
Instead of that Full name is required.

Comment: I'm not understanding the requirement as to why you need a calculated column to display data that is already displayed automatically.

Comment: Sorry if the requirements are not clear.
The problem is the data displayed under created field would be  LastName,FistName. Suppose we want to use it for email purposes, it will be displayed as domain\username. Instead of this i need to display the name as FirstName,LastName.

Comment: If you're wanting to use it in a workflow situation for emails and using SharePoint 2010, you can fetch that data automatically in the workflow.  If you're on 2007 then you need to resort to other methods as using a person/group field in a calculated column always returns domain\userid regardless of how the dta is displayed on the screen.

Comment: Am also having the same requirement in my SP 2010 site's list. But i am using Bamboo web part with email functionality, where in when one sends a email,it shows the lastname, firstname, i need to display it as FirstName, LastName. is this  possible  using calculatedFormula , either by creating a new single line of text and apply that calculatedformula in this newly created SingleLine of text.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-string type of formula. Though sub-string itself is only available in forms and workflows (not calculated columns) you can write one of your own (use LEFT, RIGHT, FIND, LEN). [See example](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/using-calculated-field-to-retrieve-substring-of-another-field)

Answer (score 0):

update 2022-01 - [Me] works on SharePoint online

Answer (score -3):

Type `=Me` in the calculated value

Comment: [Me] can only be used in View Filters and Field Defaults, not in Calculated Column Formulas, See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/151144/how-to-use-today-and-me-in-calculated-column/151336#151336