# Padding a numeric string in a calculated column

Tags: list, calculated-column

I need to pad a numeric string using a SharePoint calculated column. I have two fields, Sectiontxt and calcPadNum. For example, if a user enters 1.12.1 into Sectiontxt, I want calcPadNum to be 011201.

I know that `IF(LEN(ModuleNum)<2,0&ModuleNum,ModuleNum)` will test if the length of ModuleNum field is less than 2, and if it is, it will add a 0 before it.

*I am using MOSS 2007, and I read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) that the MID function is not supported. Is there any other (functional) option that I can use?

I know that I could add the following fields to the list ModuleNum, SectionNum, Sub_SectionNum, and then pad the number that way, but I am trying to avoid having the user enter the same info in multiple fields.

Many Thanks!

Comment: Okay, so I think it IS possible using the FIND() function, but it is going to be a seriously nested function... and nested functions are not my best. [link] (http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/using-calculated-field-to-retrieve-substring-of-another-field) Anyone?

Comment: Okay, so I'm back to my original plea. It looks like the FIND() function isn't going to help, since it only finds the first "." and doesn't go any farther, and there can be several "." that are entered.

Answer (score 1):

From your link it seems that you are using SP2010. [This](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/sharepoint-calculated-column-cheat-sheet/) post indicates that **MID()** should work.

You might try `&TEXT(ModuleNum,"00")`

in place of

`0&ModuleNum`