# Extract part character from a string using calculated column

Tags: calculated-column

I have the following string: **XXXX.C.2.0.1**

how do I extract just the "C"?

thanks

Comment: SharePoint Online? On-Premise? 2010, 2013? How do you want to get the "C"? Javascript? Directly in the form? Please give us some more information...

Comment: Maybe it's possible to do it shorter and more readable, but this should to the trick. You can replace the hardcoded string with a column if you want `=LEFT(
RIGHT("XXXX.C.2.0.1", LEN("XXXX.C.2.0.1")-INT(FIND(".","XXXX.C.2.0.1")-1)-1), INT(FIND(".",RIGHT("XXXX.C.2.0.1", LEN("XXXX.C.2.0.1")-INT(FIND(".","XXXX.C.2.0.1")-1)-1))-1))`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Source [Using calculated field to retrieve substring of another field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/using-calculated-field-to-retrieve-substring-of-another-field)
Suppose for example you have a field that contain the following data as in the above link :

```
==========================
|  Email Address         |
==========================
| Jack@wonderland.com    |
| Peter@nobodyland.com   |
| Jill@wonderland.com    |
==========================
```

And if you want to have the following result as shown below by removing the sub-strings from the Email Address column and display them in each indiviual UserName and Domain column

```
===========================================================
|  Email Address         |  UserName  |      Domain       |
===========================================================
| Jack@wonderland.com    |   Jack     |   wonderland.com  |
| Peter@nobodyland.com   |   Peter    |   nobodyland.com  |
| Jill@wonderland.com    |   Jill     |   wonderland.com  |
===========================================================
```

You can use the following method

1. Create Calculated column called "UserName" and type in this formula

   =LEFT([Email Address],INT(FIND("@",[Email Address])-1))
2. Create Calculated column called "Domain" and type in this formula

   =RIGHT([Email Address],LEN([Email Address])-INT(FIND("@",[Email Address])))

It should work.

And in your case you can modify the formula as per your needs. The above is just an example for the Calculated column formula

Comment: Seems like a copy from here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/using-calculated-field-to-retrieve-substring-of-another-field. Flag question as duplicate instead if you think it is one.

Comment: Please attribute the source Manish, blatently ripping off a question and answer without attribution may result in your post being deleted.

Comment: i did not had an option to flag the question as duplicate so i copied the answer from the above post. and i am sorry i forgto to mention the source.