# How to exact substring from string using index value in SharePoint 2010 workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow

How to create workflow where two substring can be exacted from one and can be saved in two different column of the list.
I have title like arrow_black, I want to exact arrow and black from this title.

Something like this in SharePoint using workflow

**Please note:**  I want to implement this in SharePoint 2010

Title:- Arrow_black

Icon :- Arrow

Color:- Black

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you want by using calculated columns, tedious I know but sometimes that's just SharePoint.

Try the following link to get the formula that you want to put in your columns

[Using calculated field to retrieve substring of another field](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/using-calculated-field-to-retrieve-substring-of-another-field)

Comment: Columns Icon and Color are metadata column and they are not coming up in the insert column list while using this formula.