# Formula to check if a column has one of two values and LEN=9

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I'm trying to work out a formula to check if a column has CIP or GEN as the first three characters, followed by 7 numerals. I have a formula to check for CA1234567.

`=(LEN([Order Number])=9)+(LEFT([Order Number],2)="CA")=2`

Although this does not check if there are 7 digits, just that the field is 9 characters in length.

Answer (score 1):

Of the top of my head:

```
 =AND( 
       OR( 
            LEFT( x , 3 ) = "CIP"
          , LEFT( x , 3 ) = "GEN"
         )
      , ISNUMBER( RIGHT( x , 7 ) ) 
      , LEN( x ) = 10
     )
```

All functions that actually work in Calculated Columns:

http://www.viewmaster365.com/functions

**tip:**

- use Excel, name cell A1 the name of your SharePoint Field **x**
  (*use B1, C1,.. for more named references*)
- make your Formula work in cell A2
- copy/paste in SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to combine the `ISNUMBER`, `LEFT`, and `RIGHT` functions to check each number and `AND` the results. [Syntax here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/using-calculated-field-to-retrieve-substring-of-another-field).