# Extracting string in SharePoint Calculated Column

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column

In a SharePoint List column A, I have a avalue like:

```
xx|myemail1@email.com":yy|myemail2@email.com":
```

In a calculated column, I want to get email IDs with separated by a semicolon, like:

```
myemail1@email.com;myemail2@email.com
```

Basically I want to get a string between `|` & `:`

Comment: See https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/using-calculated-field-to-retrieve-substring-of-another-field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are limited by the Functions you can use in SP, there is no `.split()` function

See: https://www.365csi.nl/vm365com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

You can test/develop in Excel, then copy paste your Formula to SP

PS. copy/paste that site, It will be gone 1/1/2018