# SharePoint calculated columns getting Currency from Single line of Text field

Tags: office-365, 2016

I have a column named Amount in Single line of Text

It has values like `300$`

Now I want to get the value of it except for the **$** symbol

I am trying `INT([Amount])`

But I would also need decimal values, so what is the best way to get just the numbers without $ from the Amount Column and assign it to calculated column?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below formula

```
=LEFT([Amount],INT(FIND("$",[Amount])-1))
```

Ref :[See Here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29140/using-calculated-field-to-retrieve-substring-of-another-field)

Answer (score 0):

Since some entries had $ and some didn't have I went with the below formula

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("$",[Amount])), RIGHT([Amount], LEN([Amount])-1) , [Amount])
```

This will check if it has $ in the beginning, and then return all items from right except $